# Evolution 3.18.5.2 cannot access Gmail on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, evolution, gmail

I have trying to get Evolution 3.18.5.2 setup on Ubuntu 16.04.

1. I have granted gnome online account access to google services. However, Evolution is still unable to access google services.
2. Experimenting, I realized that Evolution can access Gmail if I disable 2-factor authentication and allow access to gmail through less secure applications (all through google account settings).

I do not particularly like option #2. Any help would be much appreciated.

Unity Online Account Image:

[image]

Error in Evolution:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are faced with an authentication issue on the Gmail side. This may come from a settings issue in Evolution. Therefore let me post my preferences that had always worked:

#### Receiving mail:

[image]

#### Sending mail:

[image]

On first send/receive command for this Gmail account you will be asked for your password.